# sync.WaitGroup and nested loops

Tags: go, goroutine

I'd like to add concurrency for iterating nested loops but having a trouble. What's wrong with this example usage of sync.WaitGroup?

```
originCities := [3]string{"LED", "MOW", "PRS"}
destinationCities := [2]string{"UKT", "AAC"}

wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(len(originCities) * len(destinationCities))

for _, originIata := range originCities {
    for _, destinationIata := range destinationCities {
        go func () {
            fmt.Println(originIata)
            fmt.Println(destinationIata)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
}
wg.Wait()
```

I'm getting

> PRS AAC PRS AAC PRS AAC PRS AAC PRS AAC PRS AAC

So as you may see it's skipping first elements of both array and iterating only the last ones. Any ideas how to fix this behavior?

Comment: [FAQ: closures and goroutines](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a closure problem. You need to pass values to your goroutine inside the loop, like this:

```golang
for _, originIata := range originCities {
    for _, destinationIata := range destinationCities {
        go func (originIata, destinationIata string) {
            fmt.Println(originIata)
            fmt.Println(destinationIata)
            wg.Done()
        }(originIata, destinationIata)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As has been posted, one can pass the values as function parameters to the goroutine function.

Or one can use the technique of creating explicit variables within the scope of the loops. For simplicity, you can reuse the same variable name. This ensures the goroutine references the for loop's closure value (and not the externally-scoped dynamic value you were experiencing):

```
for _, originIata := range originCities {
    originIata := originIata // here
    for _, destinationIata := range destinationCities {
        destinationIata := destinationIata // here
        go func () {
            fmt.Println(originIata)
            fmt.Println(destinationIata)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
}
```

Note: the above fix will only work, if the copies are done *outside* the goroutine function.

---

**Edit:** use go tools like `go vet` and go's [race-detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector) to help catch these *gotcha* type bugs.

For example, the go playground (as well as popular editors like VScode) run `go vet` by default e.g.

https://play.golang.org/p/JhALssCu2-T

But note, **do not** rely on `go vet` as a security blanket. In the playground above, it does *not* catch the outer `o` potential race condition.

You can build your executable with a [data-race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector) (tl;dr; `go build -race` ;  use this for testing and not production - as it performs slower and has something like a 8K go-routine limit).

The race-detector will only catch data-races issues *at runtime*. So use it judiciously, as it is not a code-flow analyzer and thus cannot predict any future potential code execution issues.

Comment: I didn't know this, interesting! I don't find it very explicit for readability though.

Comment: @Clément Your answer and this answer are both suggested in the  [Go FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines). The FAQ says that this is the easier approach.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Sure, it's really only my personal preference. I still upvoted since I learned something.

Comment: I added `go vet` and race-detector info to the answer too. Curiously `go vet` does not catch the outer-loop issue, only the inner one.