# go vet: catches inner but not outer race-condition

Tags: go, race-condition, static-analysis

In a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58533613/1218512) a nested loop was being used that led to a data-race. `go vet` only caught some of the problems.

Using a simplified version:

```golang
for _, o := range ol {
        o := o // <- remove this: `go vet` does *NOT* complain
        for _, d := range dl {
            d := d // <- remove this: `go vet` will complain
            go func() {
                fmt.Printf("%03d %03d\n", o, d) // potential data-race
            }()
        }
    }
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JhALssCu2-T)

`go vet` correctly detects the inner race-condition, but not the outer one.

Why is this? Too complex to keep track of scopes deeper than 2 levels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comment [in the code](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/9525425c6f025712dbab52333bbe1574437bac61/go/analysis/passes/loopclosure/loopclosure.go#L29-L33) says:

> This analyzer checks for references to loop variables from within a
>   function literal inside the loop body. It checks only instances where
>   the function literal is called in a defer or go statement that is the
>   last statement in the loop body, as otherwise we would need whole
>   program analysis.

The `go vet` command does not complain about `o` because the go statement is not the last statement in the `o` loop.

The test is very simple and probably detects most instances of the bug. Detecting other instances of the bug requires an approach that will take more time to develop and execute.

Comment: The last phrase is the key here - "otherwise we would need whole program analysis". The check is limited for performance reasons; they *could* detect more cases, but there's a big performance trade-off, and the assumption is likely that linters are a quick check against code that will be later run through Go's built-in race detector.

Answer (score 0):

This [discussion](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16520#issuecomment-255196713) on a similar issue with Russ Cox et. al. is interesting.

Specifically this comment:

> ... this Issue is more challenging to analyze because it requires
>   proving that the function is not called within the loop, or at least
>   failing to prove that it is called within the loop. Once the anonymous
>   function has been stored in a data structure or passed to another
>   function, vet can no longer precisely determine when it might be
>   called.
>
> In other words, I think the current vet check is probably as good as
>   we can do without interprocedural analysis.